# download several files selected angular 7

Tags: node.js, angular, express

hello I'm working on a project but I have a problem I have to download several file selected of a list, is I search but I do not find a way to do it, I can download a single file to the times but not more than one file if a person can help me thank you

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find how to download several files in angular with  this code

```
 download(filename){

    console.log(filename);
    this.taskService.sendFile(filename)
      .subscribe(
        data => saveAs(data, filename),
      );
  }

  downloadAll(){

    const fileFormArray = <FormArray>this.myForm.controls.filename;
    console.log(fileFormArray);
   fileFormArray.controls.forEach((control,i)=>{
     if (control.value) {
       console.log(control.value);
       this.download(control.value);
     }

   });
```